# Как сравнить String и StringBuffer?

Tags: java, строки, equals

Нужно определить, является ли введенный текст палиндромом.
Палиндро́м — буквосочетание, слово или текст, одинаково читающееся в обоих направлениях.

```
String inputString = (new Scanner(System.in)).next();
StringBuffer reverseString = new StringBuffer(inputString);
reverseString.reverse();
System.out.println(inputString.equals(reverseString));
```

Как сравнить объекты `String` и `StringBuffer`?

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 6):

> Как сравнить объекты `String` и `StringBuffer`?

Для сравнения объектов классов `String` и `StringBuffer` их необходимо привести к *одному виду*.

В классе `StringBuffer` есть метод `toString()`, который отдает содержимое `StringBuffer` в виде объекта класса `String`. Далее можно сравнить две строки, используя метод `equals(...)`:

```
System.out.println(inputString.equals(reverseString.toString()));
```

> Почему мой вариант кода не заработал?

Давайте посмотрим реализацию метода `String.equals(...)`:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = value.length;
        if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                    return false;
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

- Сначала производится сравнение ссылок, они у Вас, очевидно, разные.
- Далее происходит проверка: является ли переданный объект объектом класса `String`. Так как Вы передаете `StringBuffer`, то `anObject instanceof String` возвращает `false` и сам метод `equals(...)` в итоге возвращает `false`.

---

PS. Есть еще класс `StringBuilder`, который идентичен классу `StringBuffer` за исключением того, что первый не синхронизирован (соответственно работает быстрее). Так что если Вы работаете в однопоточной среде, то целесообразно использовать `StringBuilder` вместо `StringBuffer`.

Comment: Вообще то лучше использовать `StringBuilder` - он быстрее, поскольку несинхронизирован, а здесь синхронизация вроде не требуется

Comment: @post_zeew, спасибо большое. Почему мой вариант кода не заработал?

Comment: @Barmaley, А я нигде и не говорю, что лучше использовать `StringBuffer`. Более того, во второй части ответа я описал этот момент.

Comment: @FIKcYS потому что вы сравниваете `String` и `StringBuffer`. Так как `inputString == reverseString` даёт `false`, равно как и `reverseString instanceof String`, то результатом работы метода `equals` в классе `String` будет `false`.

Comment: @FIKcYS, Добавил в ответ.

Comment: @post_zeew, спасибо большое. Я понял свою ошибку.

Comment: @post_zeew да я ни в чем вас не упрекаю, просто прокомментировал

Comment: @Barmaley, А, ок. Меня просто `Вообще то` смутило.

Answer (score 0):

1) С точки зрения IT: необходимо привести к одному виду. //toString()

2) Далее логика. Палиндром подразумевает одинаковое чтение, но расстановка пробелов произвольная. Перед сравнение оба объекта надо лишить пробелов. //replace(" ", "")

Например "вор кров" - палиндром. Но строка не равна "ворк ров"

3) Привести к одному регистру //toLowerCase()

Например "Воркров" и "воркроВ" не равны.

4) Подумать надо ли вешать ограничение/удаление других "лишних" символов. (знаки препинания, перевод каретки, и т.д.)

Итого по первым трем пунктам:

```
System.out.println(inputString.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "").equals(reverseString.toString().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "")));
```